# Repeat first AJAX-request after doing a second AJAX-request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send some data via Ajax to a PHP-script. The PHP-script checks if the there is a correct $_SESSION. If there is no session a modal will be displayed to let the user log in. So far so good...

No I want, that after logging in the data should be send one more time. Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(e) {
    var content = $('#anything').val();
    var id = $('#anything').attr('data-id');
    var data = { 'id': id, 'content': content };

    $.ajax({ url: "script.php", type: "POST", data: data, dataType: "json" })
    .done(function( json ) { 
        if (json.response) {
            // Everything is fine, so do something with the data
        }
        else {
            modal(login);
            // Showing modal for login. After login repeat the AJAX
        }
    });
});
```

If the user isn't logged in, a form is created and shown as a modal:

```
function modal(type) {
    if ( !$('#modal').length ) {
        if (type == "login") {
            $('body').prepend('<div id="modal"><h1>Login</h1><form id="loginform"><input type="text" name="username" class="input login_input" id="username"><input type="password" name="password" class="input login_input" id="password"><button type="submit">Login</button></form></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Now the user can do a login:

```
$(document).on('submit','#loginform',function(event){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({ url: "login.php", type: "POST", data: { 'username': username, 'password': password }, dataType: "json" })
    .done(function( json ) { 
        // User is now logged in -> Repeat sending first data
    });
});
```

But after this login, the first data should be send one more time to complete the first user-request. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the function that calls the first ajax as a separate function and that can be called from dom ready and from teh second ajax

```
function initiate() {
    var content = $('#anything').val();
    var id = $('#anything').attr('data-id');
    var data = {
        'id': id,
        'content': content
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (json) {
        if (json.response) {
            // Everything is fine, so do something with the data
        } else {
            modal('login');
            // Showing modal for login. After login repeat the AJAX
        }
    });
}
$(document).on('click', '#button', initiate);

function modal(type) {
    if (!$('#modal ').length) {
        if (type == "login") {
            $('body ').prepend(' < div id = "modal" > < h1 > Login < /h1><form id="loginform"><input type="text" name="username" class="input login_input" id="username"><input type="password" name="password" class="input login_input" id="password"><button type="submit">Login</button > < /form></div > ');
        }
    }
}

$(document).on('submit ', '#loginform ', function (event) {
    var username = $('#username ').val();
    var password = $('#password ').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (json) {
        // User is now logged in -> Repeat sending first data
        initiate();
    });
});
```

Comment: But the problem for me is, that there are a lot of different types of forms and actions. All of them need different data. So I create the var `data` before sending the ajax. How can I get the var data from the first ajax to the second ajax?